# Trouble running Ansible external module

Tags: ansible

I'm trying to use the [Jboss Module](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/jboss_module.html) in a playbook. As per example:

```
# Deploy a hello world application
- jboss:
    src: /tmp/hello-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war
    deployment: hello.war
    state: present
```

However it seems the jboss module is not recognized:

```
The offending line appears to be:

- jboss:
  ^ here
```

I've copied the jboss.py module (from https://github.com/ansible/ansible-modules-extras/blob/devel/web_infrastructure/jboss.py) in the folder defined by:

```
library        = /home/jboss/ansible/lib
```

However the error stays the same. Do I need a sort of definition of this module somewhere in order to use it? Thanks

Comment: Please provide more context within a playbook and full error message.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, however the error is pretty much this: "ERROR! 'jboss' is not a valid attribute for a Play

The error appears to have been in '/home/francesco/ansible/myplaybooks/deploy.yml': line 1, column 3, but may be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem."
As for the playbook, I've copied the above script in a file deploy.yml

Answer (score 1):

> ERROR! 'jboss' is not a valid attribute for a Play

This tells you that you have wrong playbook syntax. Either wrong indentation or wrong sections.
Should be:

```
- hosts: myhost
  tasks:
    - jboss:
        src: ...
        ...
```